# having trouble with multiple dragabblevanilla javascript modal boxes

Tags: javascript, web-applications

so im making some vanilla js draggable modal boxes but i keep having trouble when it comes to the dragging.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

    <title>Me website mate</title>
</head>
    <body>
<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <button id="buttonone" class="button">click me</button>

        <div id="boxone" class="box">
            <div id="headerone" class="header">header
                <div class="box-buttons">
                    <div id="box-close-one" class="operation-button" style="background-color: rgb(207, 9, 33);">&times</div>
                    <div id="box-maximize" class="operation-button" style="background-color: rgb(248, 201, 27);">max</div>
                    <div id="box-minimize" class="operation-button" style="background-color: rgb(0, 104, 69);">min</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                content
            </div>
            <div class="resize"></div>
        </div>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <button id="buttontwo" class="button">click me</button>
        <div id="boxtwo" class="box" style="left: 500px;">
            <div id="headertwo" class="header">header
                <div class="box-buttons">
                    <div id="box-close-two" class="operation-button" style="background-color: rgb(207, 9, 33);">&times</div>
                    <div id="box-maximize" class="operation-button" style="background-color: rgb(248, 201, 27);">max</div>
                    <div id="box-minimize" class="operation-button" style="background-color: rgb(0, 104, 69);">min</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                content
            </div>
            <div class="resize"></div>
        </div>
          
        <script src="javaScript/main.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

the html has 2 buttons and 2 modal boxes each button opening the assigned box, each box had a close button that hides said modal box

```
.box{
    /*display: none;*/
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    height: 280px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9;  
}
.header{
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden;   
    background: rgb(69, 161, 211);/*69, 161(golden ratio), 211(prime)*/
    cursor: grab;
    position: initial;
}
.box-buttons{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    right: 0em;
    top: 0em;
}
.operation-button{
    height: 31px;
    width: 31px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 248px;
}
```

some styling

```
const boxOne = document.querySelector("#boxone");
boxOne.style.display = "none";
const boxTwo = document.querySelector("#boxtwo");
boxTwo.style.display = "none";
/////
const buttonOne = document.querySelector("#buttonone");
const closeOne = document.querySelector("#box-close-one");
const headOne = document.querySelector("#headerone");
buttonOne.addEventListener("click", function open(e){
  openBox(boxOne);
});
closeOne.addEventListener("click", function close(e){
  closeBox(boxOne);
});
headOne.addEventListener("mousedown",function grab(e){
  mouseDown(boxOne, headOne,e);
});
/////
const buttonTwo = document.querySelector("#buttontwo");
const closeTwo = document.querySelector("#box-close-two");
const headTwo = document.querySelector("#headertwo");
buttonTwo.addEventListener("click",function open(e){
  openBox(boxTwo);
});
closeTwo.addEventListener("click",function close(e){
  closeBox(boxTwo);
});

function mouseDown(B,H,i){
  var box = B;
  var head = H;
  head.style.cursor = "grabbing";
  window.addEventListener("mousemove",drag);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup",drop);
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var windowWidth =window.innerWidth;
  let previousX = i.clientX;
  let previousY = i.clientY;

  function drag(i){
    let currentX = previousX - i.clientX;
    let currentY = previousY - i.clientY;
    const bounds = box.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(bounds);
    box.style.left = bounds.left - currentX + "px"; 
    box.style.top = bounds.top - currentY + "px";    
    previousX = i.clientX;
    previousY = i.clientY;
  }
  function drop(){
    head.style.cursor = "grab";
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove",drag);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup",drop);
  }
}

function openBox(rect){
  if (rect.style.display === "none") {
      rect.style.display = "block";
  }
  console.log("open");
}
function closeBox(rectClose){
  if(rectClose.style.display !== "none"){
      rectClose.style.display = "none";
  }
  console.log("close");
}
```

it opens and closes well but it seems to be having a lot of trouble when i try to drag it. it always seems to go to the bottom right of the screen for some reason. Ive tried this project before but only with a single box, the code for the single box worked great and dragged perfectly fine but when ive tried to copy the same instructions , it fails. ik that it my code rn is inefficient but rn its just a prototype. Ive tried console.log to trouble shoot it but when i do the same to the previous project which worked fine, the output of the console looks pretty much the same. i dont know if im missing something bc i am a beginner, ive never taken a class on JS, so i dont really know what to look for or how to properly debug this. I would really appreciate the help and if possible, i would like to keep it in vanilla JS for the practice.

Answer (score 0):

so after some experimenting, i boiled the answer down to the fact that the box moved 2 pixels to the right and 2 pixels down plus the movement of my mouse. I know this because I printed out the bounds variable to the console and moving my mouse only up (with a straightedge) and to the side. im still not sure what causes this however i just added a "-2" to the box.style.left and box.style.top to mitigate this problem so now the code is

box.style.left = (bounds.left - currentX) - 2 + "px";
box.style.top = (bounds.top - currentY) -2 + "px";

thank you to anybody that actually tired to figure it out and help me